# WiX Bootstrapper - difficulty detecting if software is already installed C++ redistributable, SQL Server Compact 3.5 SP2

Tags: c++, wix, bootstrapper, burn

So far (thanks to a post from Rob Mensching), my code will detect .NET 4.0 if it's installed, and it'll pass right over it. I'm not able to correctly detect Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 x86 Redistributable OR Microsoft SQL Server Compact 3.5 Service Pack 2.

My code is below. I'm learning, so I would appreciate as much constructive criticism as possible.

```
<!-- Search for .NET 4.0 -->
<util:RegistrySearch Id="NETFRAMEWORK40"
                     Root="HKLM"
                     Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Net Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full"
                     Value="Install"
                     Variable="NETFRAMEWORK40"
                     Result="value"/>
<!-- Search for Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 x86 Redistributable -->
<util:RegistrySearch Id="SearchForCPP2010X86"
                     Root="HKLM"
                     Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\VC\VCRedist\x86"
                     Value="Install"
                     Variable="CPP2010Redist"
                     Result="exists"/>
<!-- Search for Microsoft SQL Server Compact 3.5 Service Pack 2 -->
<util:RegistrySearch Id="SearchForSQLSvrCE35SP2"
                     Root="HKLM"
                     Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Compact Edition\v3.5\ENU"
                     Value="Install"
                     Variable="SQLSvrCE35SP2"
                     Result="exists"/>

<Chain>
    <!-- Install .NET 4 Full -->
    <PackageGroupRef Id="Net4Full"/>
    <!-- Install Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 x86 Redistributable -->
    <PackageGroupRef Id="MSVisCPP2010x86Redist"/>
    <!-- Install Microsoft SQL Server Compact 3.5 Service Pack 2 -->
    <PackageGroupRef Id="SQLExpressCE"/>
</Chain>


<!-- Install .NET 4.0 -->
<PackageGroup Id="Net4Full">
    <ExePackage Id="Net4Full"
                Name="Microsoft .NET Framework 4.0 Setup"
                Cache="no"
                Compressed="yes"
                PerMachine="yes"
                Permanent="yes"
                Vital="yes"
                SourceFile="BootstrapperLibrary\dotNetFx40_Full_setup.exe"
                DetectCondition="NETFRAMEWORK40"/>
</PackageGroup>

<!-- Install Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 x86 Redistributable -->
<PackageGroup Id="MSVisCPP2010x86Redist">
    <ExePackage Id="MSVisCPP2010x86Redis"
                Name="Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 x86 Redistributable "
                Cache="no"
                Compressed="yes"
                PerMachine="yes"
                Permanent="yes"
                Vital="yes"
                SourceFile="BootstrapperLibrary\vcredist_x86.exe"
                DetectCondition="CPP2010Redist"/>
</PackageGroup>

<!-- Install Microsoft SQL Server Compact 3.5 Service Pack 2 -->
<PackageGroup Id="SQLExpressCE">
   <ExePackage Id="SQLExpressCE"
               Name="Microsoft SQL Server Compact 3.5 Service Pack 2 Setup"
               Cache="no"
               Compressed="yes"
               PerMachine="yes"
               Permanent="yes"
               Vital="yes"
               SourceFile="BootstrapperLibrary\SSCERuntime-ENU.exe"/>
</PackageGroup>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to come up with the following solution. It's not ideal, but it works for now. We were given a very short amount of time to come up with something, so this is what "works" for now.

I had to go back to the documentation several more times and eventually discovered what I needed and what I was doing wrong. Again, this is an "it works sort of" solution to my problem.

[WiX manual](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/)

[WiX tutorial](http://wix.tramontana.co.hu/tutorial)

I was also able to get a copy of the book "WiX 3.6: A Developer's Guide to Windows Installer XML" which proved to be useful. It would have been extremely useful, had it been available from day one.

My only complaint with the online WiX tutorial is that it does not have a copy (that I could find) that is based here in the US. I had to submit a request to have the website approved through our network security department. I now have access, but I had to wait a day to utilize it. When you're on a very tight development cycle, one day is a big deal.

Originally, part of my story was to search for both the 32- and 64-bit versions of SQL Server CE. I had a little trouble with the 64-bit version and ran out of time, so I used the attached file to download both the 32- and 64-bit installation files when applicable.

```
<!--Search for .NET 4.0-->
<util:RegistrySearch Id="NETFRAMEWORK40"
                     Root="HKLM"
                     Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Net Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full"
                     Value="Install"
                     Variable="NETFRAMEWORK40"
                     Result="value"/>
<!--Search for Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 x86 Redistributable-->
<util:RegistrySearch Root="HKLM"
                     Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\VC\VCRedist\x86"
                     Variable="CPP2010Redist"
                     Value="Installed"
                     Result="value"/>
<!--Search for Microsoft SQL Server Compact 3.5 Service Pack 2 x86-->
<util:RegistrySearch Id="SqlCeRegistryx86"
                     Root="HKLM"
                     Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Compact Edition\v3.5\ENU"
                     Variable="SQLSvrCE35SP2x86"
                     Win64="no"
                     Result="exists"/>


<Chain>
  <!-- Install .Net 4 Full -->
  <PackageGroupRef Id="Net4Full"/>
  <!-- Install Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 x86 Redistributable -->
  <PackageGroupRef Id="MSVisCPP2010x86Redist"/>
  <!-- Install Microsoft SQL Server Compact 3.5 Service Pack 2 x86 -->
  <PackageGroupRef Id="SQLExpressCEx86"/>
</Chain>


<Fragment Id="Prerequisites">
<!--.NET 4.0-->
<PackageGroup Id="Net4Full">
  <ExePackage Id="Net4Full"
              Cache="no"
              Compressed="yes"
              PerMachine="yes"
              Permanent="yes"
              Vital="yes"
              SourceFile="BootstrapperLibrary\dotNetFx40_Full_setup.exe"
              DetectCondition="NETFRAMEWORK40"/>
</PackageGroup>
<!--Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 x86 Redistributable-->
<PackageGroup Id="MSVisCPP2010x86Redist">
  <ExePackage Id="MSVisCPP2010x86Redist"
              Cache="no"
              Compressed="yes"
              PerMachine="yes"
              Vital="yes"
              SourceFile="BootstrapperLibrary\vcredist_x86.exe"
              DetectCondition="CPP2010Redist"/>
</PackageGroup>
<!--Microsoft SQL Server Compact 3.5 Service Pack 2 x86-->
<PackageGroup Id="SQLExpressCEx86">
  <ExePackage Id="SQLExpressCEx86"
              Cache="no"
              Compressed="yes"
              PerMachine="yes"
              Vital="yes"
              SourceFile="BootstrapperLibrary\SSCERuntime-ENU.exe"
              DetectCondition="SQLSvrCE35SP2x86"/>
</PackageGroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

Surely, detection is the job of the redistributable. I would only try to reproduce it myself if the redistributable was known to have scenarios with undesirable behaviors (that is, is broken). Even then I would look for official documentation first.

Microsoft's Aaron Stebner's say in his personal [blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2010/05/05/10008146.aspx):

> Overall, my recommendation for the VC++ redistributable packages is to
>   not bother to try to detect if the package is already installed. 
>   Instead, I recommend that you always install them during your
>   installation process.

Your installer's declared goal is for the end state of VC 2010 runtime libraries to be functional at a certain service pack level. It communicates this goal to the redistributable, and it (hopefully) achieves it efficiently through whatever installation and/or repair process it deems necessary.

The key things to get right in an ExePackage are the `InstallCommand` and `ExitCode`s. Ideally, these would be officially documented. Exit codes are somewhat standardized to indicate failure, success with reboot required now, success with now reboot required (see the [first note](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376931%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).

Comment: I agree you're right in principle, but it can be annoying to force the user to download a couple megabytes that might not be needed (with a remote payload).

Comment: @Cameron That's a valid point for large packages that could be downloaded. For those cases, hopefully the package vendor provides their own web-based installer, such as Microsoft does for the .NET Framework. There is a disadvantage to this middle route, though, because the bundle's `/layout` command will only pull down the vendor's web-based installer and installing the bundle will still require an Internet connection.

Comment: @TomBlodget  I was tasked with searching for an existing installation of each piece of software in an attempt to reduce the time required for each installation.  If we download every file every time, it would simply not be efficient.  There's proprientary software also included with the installation, so I could not add it to the list above.  Thanks for your suggestion, though.

Comment: Your and Cameron's goals have do value for end-users. However, you have to realize what you are doing: Re-implementing a potentially undocumented portion of a third-party's installer. Admittedly, it's a small portion. And, it would be low risk if they documented it accurately. One has to find the right compromise for every project. I wish I could point you to the installer documentation for those packages.