# Wix condition evaluation

Tags: wix, conditional-statements

I have a **wix** project and inside it I am checking whether **c++ redist 2015** is installed or not as followings:

```
    <Property Id="CPP2015REDISTX64">
  <RegistrySearch Id="CPP2015RedistX64_RegKey" Type="raw" Root="HKLM" 
                  Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\VC\VCRedist\x64"
                  Name="Installed"
                  Win64="yes"/>
</Property>

<Condition Message='[Error Message]'>
  CPP2015REDISTX64
</Condition>
```

When I try to install the package it shows me an error,but when I check my computer registries I can see it installed [image]

I am wondering what's wrong with my code (I know that if the value of the Installed key is found it will proceed with the installation process and the condition will evaluate to true)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to MSDN page [Redistributing Visual C++ Files](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235299.aspx), the correct registry key to check is:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\VC\Runtimes\x64
```

That matches what I see on my machine using regedit.exe.

So replace "VCRedist" by "Runtime". Also make sure that you specify `-arch x64` on the candle.exe command-line (alternatively set `Package/@Platform="x64"`, but the docs state that "use of this attribute is discouraged").

Comment: Yea it worked, but I got confused with the answer of this question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23943920/wix-bootstrapper-difficulty-detecting-if-software-is-already-installed-c-red but it was for c++ redist 2010

Comment: @Waddah MS are not very consistent with their registry keys :-(